# call my jQuery function after Primefaces script is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

**Description:**

When using Primefaces html page is rendered by Servlet. Sometimes Servlet generates only html tags, but sometimes generates javascript.

*Case 1*

XHTML:

```html
<h:outputText id="outputId" value="Hello!!!" />
```

Generated:

```html
<span id="outputId">Hello!!!</span>
```

In this case it is very easy to add addtional callback using jQuery script. Beacouse all html elements are already generated.

*Case 2:*

XHTML:

```html
<p:schedule id="bigCalendarId" value="#{csController.lazyEventModel} view="month" />
```

This example shows that not always pure html is generated. In this case javascipt is generated:

```html
<script id="formId:bigCalendarId_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Schedule','widget_formId_bigCalendarId',{id:'formId:bigCalendarId',defaultView:'month',offset:3600000,header:{left:'prev,next today',center:'title',right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'}},'schedule');});</script>
```

So Primefaces use some script to finish initialization. This function is called when DOM tree is built.

**Question:**

Primafaces uses script to build view, but I would like to add some calbacks to generated content. Problem is that my script **has to** be executed after javascript generated by Primefaces is finished.
How to achieve that? How to execute my script after Primefaces?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways that work for me, when I want to execute a JS function after page load in Primefaces:

- either use jQuery (as it is already used by Primefaces), best solution is to nest document.ready twice, so that my JS code is executed after all Primefaces code:

  - `jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
             // twice in document.ready to execute after Primefaces callbacks
             myInitialisationFunction();
        });
    });`
- or use p:remoteCommand with autorun, and place oncomplete JS callback on it

  - this way form is submitted by AJAX to server but no listener executed on server side, a JS callback is executed afterwards
  - `<p:remoteCommand oncomplete=" myInitialisationFunction(); " autoRun="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the PrimeFaces version you are using. However, as of PrimeFaces 7.0 there is no such event as *PrimeFaces is ready*. This was [stated by](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=174522#p174522) *tandraschko*, a PrimeFaces core developer in 2019.

His suggestion was, to add a [jQuery ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)-handler **at the end** of your page, which should add the ready()-handler **after** PrimeFaces (which actually does the same thing for initialization).

Adding a ready()-handler at the end could be done directly via `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>` in your XHTML code, or by using OmniFaces' [`<o:onloadScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript) component, which could be placed anywhere in XHTML but will be relocated to the end in the resulting HTML. Here is some example code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <o:onloadScript rendered="#{not faces.ajaxRequest}">
    $(function() {
      console.log('PrimeFaces now ready.');
    })
  </o:onloadScript>

  <!-- your JSF and PrimeFaces components go here... -->

</ui:composition>
```

I also tried the suggestion from *OndroMih* with nested ready()-handlers, which seems to work as well.